# React Installation (npm ERR! SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to run my first React application. 
I've installed Node.js/npm.

I tried executing the command "**npx create-react-app my-app**" as per the tutorial on https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

I also tried another command "**npm install -g create-react-app@1.5.2**", but there seems to be an error.

Please refer to the image-
[commands executed on cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMizE.jpg)

I have watched multiple installation guides and video tutorials but nothing seems to work.
Please help me out!

Comment: Whats the errror ?

Comment: Run: `npm config set ca ""` then try again OR `npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"`

Comment: Check this out [here](https://acloud.guru/forums/the-complete-serverless-course/discussion/-L_I1pVFgThg4yq7li2j/npx%20create-react-app%20failing%20on%20self%20signed%20certificate)

Comment: Try to run the cmd with admin priviledges.

Comment: Please include code and results in your question as text, not as pictures. Pictures don't always render well, may not be readable by some people on some devices, can't be searched as easily and can't be copied to try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update npm

```
npm install npm -g --ca NULL
```

and then tell npm to use know registrars for SSL cert verification with

```
npm config set ca=""
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The error remains the same- npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.2.tgz failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-04T16_14_51_726Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1

Comment: The error is something like this-extract: WARN tarball tarball data for tar@^2.2.1 (sha512-FCEhQ/4rE1zYv9rYXJw/msRqsnmlje5jHP6huWeBZ704jUTy02c5AZyWujpMR1ax6mVw9NyJMfuK2CMDWVIfgA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more